# Schedule iOS Push Notification with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, notifications, background-process

I am trying to schedule push notifications using Parse in iOS. I only have a free account (meaning that I cannot schedule notifications in the web backend), so I came up with a solution for scheduling the notification through Parse:

Within the app, when you press send notification you set the text and a date to send the notification (using the code to just send a standard PFPush code). Then I just use NSDate and every day check the date to see if it matches the date for the scheduled notification. If it does, it sends the notification; thus sending the notification on the scheduled day, if it is not the matching day, nothing happens (no notification is sent, and the app rechecks in another 24hrs). This works, but the app has to be open in the foreground at the time that the notification is scheduled for sending (i.e the date is not checked and notification not sent if the app is in the background). So my actual question is how I can run all of this in the background, so the app can just be in the background on my iPad, and it will still check the date and be able to post the PFPush (push notification).

Any help or code would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance, and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: If you are using IOS7 you can use this method and you should register for backgroundMode in info plist - (void) application: (UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
  (void(^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {}

Comment: Oh, sorry for the ambiguity. Yes, I am using iOS 7. I will try that code and let you know if it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case

setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval means that it is not called in an interval which is smaller than the value you specified. But there's no setMaximumBackgroundFetchInterval. So if iOS decides to call your app just once a day or even just once a week than it won't be called more often regardless your minimumBackgroundFetchInterval. AFAIK iOS decides when to call performFetchWithCompletionHandler measured by the pattern when and how often the users start's the app.

In Xcode 5 Debug mode, you can force a background fetch from the menu: Debug > Simulate Background Fetch.[image]